# Search by date works with SQLite but throws error ORA_00936 with Oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, sqlite

I have this error:

> OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, date("T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"."CREATED_AT") AS date_t_order_product_items_cre 
  FROM "T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"  
  GROUP BY date("T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"."CREATED_AT")
```

It works fine with group by id.

I use SQLite and nothing wrong. But when I upload to server with Oracle, I have this error.

I use this query in SQLite:

```
Transaction::OrderProductItem.group('date(created_at)').count
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has a [`DATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) *function*, but not Oracle.

You need to use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) to convert from varchar to date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,
       to_date("T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"."CREATED_AT", "DD-MM-YYYY") AS date_t_order_product_items_cre 
--                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                                                 your date format
FROM "T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"  
GROUP BY to_date("T_ORDER_PRODUCT_ITEMS"."CREATED_AT", "DD-MM-YYYY");
--                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                                                   your date format
```

While not strictly necessary, it is a good practice to explicitly set the date format when using `TO_DATE`. Otherwise, it defaults to the [format corresponding to your locale configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817)  -- and if this changes for whatever reason it will lead to difficult to track bugs.

SQLite, [does not have a proper data type for date/time](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). But, in Oracle it is always preferable to store date directly in a `DATE` column. This avoid conversion on the fly while doing queries. Not mentioning that using a function will invalidate the index you might have on that column.

However, *if you really need a cross-product solution*, your best bet is probably to store your date as strings using a lexicographically comparable date/time format. Like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) -- and completely get rid of using a *proper* date type and/or date functions. For simple search/ordering this will work. But if will increase complexity when you will need to extract date components or perform calculations.

That being said, if it is a requirement for your project to be compatible both with SQLite and Oracle (and possibly other DB), it might worth considering using some abstraction layer between your code and the generated SQL (like [SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html) for Python -- I'm pretty sure such things exist for Ruby as well:).

Comment: Thank you, but can i use somthing to work with both sqllite and oracle ?

Comment: @user3422283 At raw SQL level, I can't see any such solution. Maybe you could simply store your data in a `DATE` column. that would get rid of the problem (in this statement, at least) ?

Comment: @user3422283 ... or store date as varchar ( :/ ) but ensuring you are using a lexicographically comparable date format? See my edit for some details.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking about checking type of database before use sql querry

Comment: @user3422283 _"i was thinking about checking type of database"_ That's one solution. Depending your project size and requirement, you could either come with your own SQL abstraction layer or consider using some external library for that purpose. I don't know well the Ruby ecosystem (and such recommendations are considered off-topic on SO), but I'm pretty sure such things exists.